# json generating array problems

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to generate a json array and store it in my db.
I get the values and run a loop to generate.

when I encode it I'm getting  ArrayArrayArray

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$sTotal;$i++){ 
    $layout_array .= array(array("cellID" => '"'. $_POST['cell_'.$i] .'"',"studentID" => $_POST['user_'.$i]),);
}
$layout_array .= array(array("cellID" => "null","studentID" => "null"));
$layout = json_encode($layout_array);
echo $layout;
```

Cheers

Comment: why are you concatenating `$layout_array`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `$layout_array` is a `String` , because you're using `.=` (concatenating).

Instead of:

```
$layout_array .= array(array("cellID" => '"'. $_POST['ce...
```

Do:

```
$layout_array[] = array(array("cellID" => '"'. $_POST['ce....
```

And change the next line as well:

```
$layout_array .= array(array("cellID" => "null","studentID" => "null"));
```

**BTW** , why not using `serialize` and `unserialize` instead of json encoding?

**EDIT:** For your comfort , links to the php manual of the functions I've suggested.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `+=` to join your arrays, not `.`.

Edit: Ignore this and see comments. This will add elements to the current scope of the array, you should be using `$array[] = array(..)` as the other answer states.

Comment: I'm fully aware it's PHP! You use .= with strings, += with numbers and arrays.

Comment: @sircapsalot: `.=` is for concatenating. `+=` is for adding. Both are valid PHP operators.  But I don't think I've ever seen either used for adding new elements to an array.

Comment: To be honest this answer will not as expected. It's fully valid PHP but to add a new element to an array it will not work. I was thinking of the array() + array() syntax.